# Living or Non-Living?

Tags: machine-learning, entity, dictionary, llm

```
lst = {"pear", "apple", "shirt", "lion", "dog", "orange", "fish", 
   "candy", "basket", "coat", "grape", "wolf", "human", "lamp", 
   "banana", "horse", "shoe", "virus"};
```

As a first step in categorizing a list of general items, I was wondering if items in `lst` can be separated according to whether these are alive or not using Mathematica's `Entity` system? Dictionary lookup techniques or other workarounds would be appreciated as much.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT-1**

Upon receiving comments by @Roman and @bmf, I have added "virus" to the list, and tried "Species" with the `Interpreter` command.

```
Interpreter["Species"][#] & /@ lst /. _Failure :> Nothing
```

[image]

I would say that "Species" is more granular than what I need, but it could be a valid indicator of life.

---

**EDIT-2**

A good answer by @JoshuaSchrier, and a workable technique using the recently introduced `LLM` functions. An apple tree would be considered a living object but once an apple is plucked, it would be considered an edible non-living object; or at least that's how most, if not all, humans interpret it. The `LLM` output considers `pear` and `banana` as non-living objects while an `apple` and an `orange` as living ones which is inconsistent. I use v12.2.0 so I cannot test it on my own but perhaps the query can be modified.

About the virus; it can be considered alive in that it is seeking a host, but it is for the experts to debate. The question is a bit loaded and if narrowed down can be dealt with better. For instance, given a picture with identified objects (or a list of items), a threat assessment would consider `lion` a bigger red flag compared to a `shoe`. A lethal `virus` wouldn't count, but that's contextual and would require more work on identification of the virus species and how exposed the observers are to it.

Both techniques (`Interpreter` and `LLM` functions) require live internet access to an available and paid external resource.

---

Comment: What should be the answer for `"virus"`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `TextCases[stuff,"Species"]`? For instance, like the examples [`here`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/textcontent/Species.html)?

Comment: It's an interesting philosophical question. Is a fly "more alive" than a virus, a growing crystal more than a shrinking candy, an apple more than a stone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you opened the case for "other workarounds"--Here's a way you can do it with the new [LLMFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LLMFunction.html) in 13.3  (by default will use GPT-3.5, Temperature = 0K as default):

```mathematica
aliveQ = LLMFunction["Decide whether the following word is alive or not.  Return only the word \"True\" if it is alive and \"False\" if it is not alive:\n``", 
   "Boolean"]
```

Up to you whether you think the answers make sense. It gets objectively living and non-living things correct, but I don't know if a pear or apple should be defined as living, and neither does GPT-3.

```mathematica
lst = {"pear", "apple", "shirt", "lion", "dog", "orange", "fish", "candy", "basket", "coat", "grape", "wolf", "human", "lamp", "banana", "horse", "shoe", "virus"};

AssociationMap[aliveQ, lst]

(*<|"pear" -> False, "apple" -> True, "shirt" -> False, "lion" -> True, "dog" -> True, "orange" -> True, "fish" -> True, "candy" -> False, "basket" -> False, "coat" -> False, "grape" -> True, "wolf" -> True, "human" -> True, "lamp" -> False, "banana" -> False, "horse" -> True,"shoe" -> False, "virus" -> True|>*)
```

If you don't like the answers you might think about changing the query ("Was once or is now living?") or using GPT-4 instead. Alternatively, if you have some known examples you can use [LLMExampleFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LLMExampleFunction.html)

Comment: Thanks for this workable technique. I will edit in my thoughts as EDIT-2.

Comment: A query like `LLMFunction["If the following is a plant or animal or fungus or
bacterium then answer TRUE, otherwise answer FALSE:\n``", "Boolean"]` seems to have the desired behavior (classifies apples and pears as alive.  Viruses could be added or not if you wish)